# Buscar con comodín en Mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo una base de datos con tres tablas publicaciones, registrador y tipo de cuenta
las bases de datos no están relacionadas y estoy tratando de hacer esta consulta

```
SELECT *
FROM publicaciones 
LEFT JOIN registrados ON RegistradoID = Publ_Registrado
LEFT JOIN registrados ON tipo_Registrado = RegistradoID   
WHERE Publ_TipoUsuario = 'tipoUsuarioUno'
AND Publ_Conferencia = 'convocatoria'
AND CONCAT(Reg_Nombre, ' ', Reg_Apellidos) LIKE '%$datoBuscar%'
OR Reg_Nombre LIKE '%$datoBuscar%' 
OR Reg_Apellidos LIKE '%$datoBuscar%'
OR Publ_Contenido LIKE '%$datoBuscar%'
OR Reg_Nombre LIKE '%$datoBuscar%'
OR Reg_Apellidos LIKE '%$datoBuscar%'
OR Reg_Escolaridad LIKE '%$datoBuscar%'
OR Reg_Genero LIKE '%$datoBuscar%'
OR Reg_Pais LIKE '%$datoBuscar%'
OR Reg_Estado LIKE '%$datoBuscar%'
OR Reg_Ciudad LIKE '%$datoBuscar%'
OR Reg_Empresa LIKE '%$datoBuscar%'
or Reg_Ocupacion LIKE '%$datoBuscar%'
ORDER BY PublicacionID ASC LIMIT $inicio, $limite
```

hace bien su función de buscar el problema es que no me respeta `AND Publ_Conferencia = 'convocatoria'` y me trae todos los tipos de `Publ_Conferencia` que son cuatro
Resumen
convocatoria
presentación
conferencia

mi pregunta concreta es si estoy poniendo mal el orden de `AND` y `OR`o simplemente esa consulta es completamente incorrecta en otras búsquedas con menos parámetros funciona correctamente

por favor indiquenme si puedo ser mas claro o subir mas información

si quito

```
WHERE Publ_TipoUsuario = 'tipoUsuarioUno'
AND Publ_Conferencia = 'convocatoria'
```

la búsqueda se hace correctamente

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías ser así segun lo he entendido

```
SELECT *
FROM publicaciones 
LEFT JOIN registrados ON RegistradoID = Publ_Registrado
LEFT JOIN registrados ON tipo_Registrado = RegistradoID   
WHERE Publ_TipoUsuario = 'tipoUsuarioUno'
AND Publ_Conferencia = 'convocatoria'
AND CONCAT(Reg_Nombre, ' ', Reg_Apellidos) LIKE '%$datoBuscar%'
AND (
Reg_Nombre LIKE '%$datoBuscar%'
OR Reg_Apellidos LIKE '%$datoBuscar%'
OR Publ_Contenido LIKE '%$datoBuscar%'
OR Reg_Nombre LIKE '%$datoBuscar%'
OR Reg_Apellidos LIKE '%$datoBuscar%'
OR Reg_Escolaridad LIKE '%$datoBuscar%'
OR Reg_Genero LIKE '%$datoBuscar%'
OR Reg_Pais LIKE '%$datoBuscar%'
OR Reg_Estado LIKE '%$datoBuscar%'
OR Reg_Ciudad LIKE '%$datoBuscar%'
OR Reg_Empresa LIKE '%$datoBuscar%'
or Reg_Ocupacion LIKE '%$datoBuscar%')
ORDER BY PublicacionID ASC LIMIT $inicio, $limite
```

Si ves que no lo he entendido bien puedes añadir en esta página el ejemplo concreto para poder tener más información y un sitio donde probar

https://sqltest.net/

Comment: Al parecer la consulta funciona gracias creo me faltaban los paréntesis